# Adding Google Play to Unity Project -> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.games.PlayGames

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I have a Unity 2020.3.32f1 game and need to fix Google Play login. I upgraded to 0.11.1

Now I get an exception

> AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.games.PlayGames

when I try to init the library

> > ```
> >    public GooglePlayService()
> >    {
> >        InitStatus = InitStatus.NotInitialized;
> >        LoginStatus = LoginStatus.NotLoggedIn;
> >        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
> >        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
> >        Log("PlayGamesPlatform.Activated");
> >    }
> > ```

Following their instructions on adding Proguard and minify did not help.

I am a bit of an Android noob so it's probably something basic.

Notes:

- I ran the Android dependency resolver.
- Minify is turned on for release
- Min API Level 19
- Target API level 30
- I am using the internal build system
- No strange characters in my project path

Comment: Hi, did you or anyone solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried to change this line of code in GooglePlayGamesPluginDependencies.xml form this

```
<repository>Packages/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository</repository>
```

to this

```
<repository>Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository</repository>
```

I hope this help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).